# Microsoft Dynmaics NAV 5.0 nas process queue is not running jobs in ready status

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

We have 2 manufacturing plants (e.g. same database, different tables) using the NAS process queue with the same service. One of the plants is running fine and the other has all of its jobs stuck in the "Ready" status unless we run the code unit manually. Any ideas what may be causing one of the queues not to run on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Job Scheduler to run there has to be a NAS service running. Check the status of that windows service. Make sure its running and can login.

Comment: Restarting the Navision application service in windows services may give you some hints in the event log. 
You can also start the NAS in debug mode. To get more information regarding this service.

Comment: We were experiencing some server timeout issues that disrupted our service. We stopped and started the NAS service and everything began running as normal. Thanks for the help!